# DllImport static C++ library in C# Unity3d

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, plugins, static-libraries, dllimport

For simple signature of function everything just:

```
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
public static extern MyFunc(int a);
```

How can it for function as

```
static App* Create(const AppOptions& options, JNIEnv* jni_env,
                 jobject activity);
```

What replace of pointers and references in C ++ for C#?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  [Marshaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

**Example:**

```
/* unmanaged code declarations */

 struct UnmanagedStruct {
    int n;
 };

 void PassByValue (struct UnmanagedStruct s);

 void PassByReferenceIn (struct UnmanagedStruct *s);
 void PassByReferenceOut (struct UnmanagedStruct *s);
 void PassByReferenceInOut (struct UnmanagedStruct *s);

 struct UnmanagedStruct ReturnByValue ();
 struct UnmanagedStruct* ReturnByReference ();

 void DoubleIndirection (struct UnmanagedStruct **s);
```

The class wrapper could be:

```
/* note: sequential layout */
 [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 class ClassWrapper {
    public int n;

    /* cannot wrap function PassByValue */

    /* PassByReferenceIn */
    [DllImport ("mylib")]
    public static extern
       void PassByReferenceIn (ClassWrapper s);

    /* PassByReferenceOut */
    [DllImport ("mylib")]
    public static extern
       void PassByReferenceOut ([Out] ClassWrapper s);

    /* PassByReferenceInOut */
    [DllImport ("mylib")]
    public static extern
       void PassByReferenceInOut ([In, Out] ClassWrapper s);

    /* cannot wrap function ReturnByValue */

    /* ReturnByReference */
    [DllImport ("mylib")]
    public static extern ClassWrapper ReturnByReference ();
       /* note: this causes returned pointer to be freed
          by runtime */
     /* DoubleIndirection */
    [DllImport ("mylib")]
    public static extern
       void DoubeIndirection (ref ClassWrapper s);
 }
```

Here are some useful links:

1. [Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/)
2. [Marshaling with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66245/Marshaling-with-Csharp-Chapter-1-Introducing-Marsh.aspx)
3. [Default Marshaling for Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x07fbw8(v=vs.110).aspx)